# Cannot read property 'value' of null. when i'm in other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my website i use one javascript file called " backend.js "
contain javascript/jquery codes for all the website pages

so, for example in a function with a line like this :

```
var latit = document.getElementById('lat').value;
```

it works fine on a page that contains id='lat'
but in other pages i got this error in console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

and also with style :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

and it causes stop of executing my other functions below the line.

the same with any line with `document.getElementById` code in all my file.

---

i found a solution but i don't know if it's the best or there is better

my solution it to make a test for any `document.getElementById` in my file like this :

```
if (document.getElementById('lat') != null) {
    var latit = document.getElementById('lat').value;
}
```

is it the best solution ?

Comment: With vanilla js this is how you would do it. With jQuery, you could do it that way: `var latit = $('#lat').val();` and if `latit` is `undefined` then you know that either the element with the id `lat` does not exists or that it does not have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call `getElementById` twice. You can store the result of the first call in a variable.

```
var lat = document.getElementById('lat');
if(lat) {
  var latit = lat.value;
}
```

If you don't want additional variables, you can also use

```
var latit = (document.getElementById('lat') || {}).value;
```

or `|| Object.create(null)` if you are afraid `Object.prototype.value` might exist.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting those errors is that the web app you are writing has various states and not all of them have the elements you are specifying.

If this is a problem with a SPA web app (single page app), you need to effect some degree of *routing* so that you are only loading the appropriate javascript for each *page* in the app.

If this is a libary used on many pages, you need to check the page it is on and assume only the elements that should be there are there.

If this is a library only used on one page, it is a dynamically changing but non-SPA web app, and you need to check the *application state* and assume only the elements that should be there are there.